# move one image from one activity to another activity in android on selecting gridview

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, android-intent

i have a grid view which contain images when click on one image it should open in a another page.ie i need to pass the image from one activity to another where i want to get the pixels of the image.i have the code to get the pixels.what i need is that i have to show the image in anther activity so that to get the pixels.how to pass the selected image from one activity to another in android .i have tried some of the solution from stack overflow but it did not worked

//GridviewActivity.java

> package gr.ed.vi;

```
          import android.app.Activity;
              import android.content.Context;
                import android.content.Intent;
           import android.os.Bundle;
           import android.view.View;
           import android.view.ViewGroup;
           import android.widget.AdapterView;
            import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
              import android.widget.GridView;
             import android.widget.ImageView;
                   import android.widget.Toast;
            import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

      public class GridviewActivity extends Activity
    {    
    //---the images to display---
     Integer[] imageIDs = {
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher                    
};

@Override    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, 
        View v, int position, long id) 
        {                
           /* Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "pic" + (position + 1) + " selected", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
            switch(position){
           case 0:

           break;
           case 1:
           //call second class
              Intent intent = new Intent(GridviewActivity.this, sm.class);

         //  intent.putExtra("photo",imageIDs);
           //  Log.d(TAG, "jpegCallback1" +data);
            startActivity(intent); 

             // intent.putExtra("img", imageIDs);
             //startActivity(intent);

           break;
           case 2:
           //call third class
               Intent k1=new Intent(GridviewActivity.this,sm.class);
               startActivity(k1);
           break;

           default:
           break;
               }
        }
    });        
   }

   public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {
    private Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
    {
        context = c;
    }

    //---returns the number of images---
    public int getCount() {
        return imageIDs.length;
    }

    //---returns the ID of an item--- 
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //---returns an ImageView view---
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
        return imageView;
       }
   }    
  }
```

sm.java

```
package gr.ed.vi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BlurMaskFilter;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.AvoidXfermode.Mode;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BlurMaskFilter.Blur;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class sm extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Bitmap overlay;      
Paint pTouch;
int X = -100;
int Y = -100;
Canvas c2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    byte[] photo = extras.getByteArray("photo");
    Bitmap mBitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (photo, 0, photo.length);
    Bitmap mBitmapover  = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (photo, 0, photo.length);

             getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,              
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   // Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),         
    R.drawable.android);
   // Bitmap mBitmapover = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ss);
    overlay =   
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource                 
   (getResources(),R.drawable.ss).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);  
    c2 = new Canvas(overlay);

    pTouch = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);         
  //  pTouch.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.TARGET); 
    pTouch.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    pTouch.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, Blur.NORMAL));
    setContentView(new BitMapView(this, mBitmap,mBitmapover));
}

class BitMapView extends View {
    Bitmap mBitmap = null;
    Bitmap mBitmapover = null;

    public BitMapView(Context context, Bitmap bm, Bitmap bmover) {
    super(context);
    mBitmap = bm;
    mBitmapover = bmover;
    }
     @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

         switch (ev.getAction()) {

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                 X = (int) ev.getX();
                 Y = (int) ev.getY();
                 invalidate();

                 break;
             }

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                     X = (int) ev.getX();
                     Y = (int) ev.getY();
                     invalidate();
                     break;

             }           

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                 break;

         }
         return true;
     }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // called when view is drawn
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    // The image will be scaled so it will fill the width, and the
    // height will preserve the imageâ€™s aspect ration
/*  double aspectRatio = ((double) mBitmap.getWidth()) / mBitmap.getHeight();
    Rect dest = new Rect(0, 0, this.getWidth(),(int) (this.getHeight() / aspectRatio));
    double aspectRatio2 = ((double) mBitmapover.getWidth()) / mBitmapover.getHeight();
    Rect dest2 = new Rect(0, 0, this.getWidth(),(int) (this.getHeight() / aspectRatio2));
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, null, dest, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapover, null, dest2, paint);                    */

    //draw background
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    //copy the default overlay into temporary overlay and punch a hole in it                          
    c2.drawBitmap(mBitmapover, 0, 0, null); //exclude this line to show all as you draw
    c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 80, pTouch);
    //draw the overlay over the background  
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**when you click a image get the paht/uri of that image and create intent and put the value with intent and get it in another activity and show it.*

ex:

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
              int i=R.drawable.ic_launcher;

             Intent intent = new Intent(SamaaActivity.this,kl.class); 
            intent.putExtra("intVariableName", i);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

and get this on other activity

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
```

Comment: idont need to get image from the sd card i have alrady placed images on the drawable folder

Comment: private void showImage() {
    String uri = "drawable/icon";


    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(image);
}

Comment: pass the uri to next activity

Answer (score 0):

you can get image id when select item and pass id to second activity and retrieve image based on that or you can pass image from one to second using `static` variable with `Bitmap` so when it get select just display those image easily

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the uri of the image as extras in the intent used to invoke the second activity. This way you will avoid decoding the data until the point you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

[Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) already implements [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), simply put your bitmap into intent and pass it to next activity.

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Bitmap image = imageAdapter.getItem(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("details", image);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

**UPDATE:**
Better to change your ImageAdapter.getItem() implementation to return a ImageView or Bitmap, to convert imageView to Bitmap, simply do this:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

To retrieve Bitmap from NextActivity:

```
Parcelable details = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("details");
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) details;
```