# Gridview image should link to another activity

Tags: android, gridview

I referred [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/) for making a gridview. Now what i want is if i touch one image in gridview it should link me to the next activity in the screen. Totally i have 5 images in my activity and if i touch those images every image needs to display five different activity. i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832771/move-one-image-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-android-on-selcting-grid) but couldn't do what i want. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));

// USE this here and implement as acording by using 'position'
        imageView.setOnClickListener();
        return imageView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Switch stament and change it on the basis of position..

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
          {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.list);
            GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv);
            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
             switch(position)
                {
                case 0:               
                    Intent ammissione = (new Intent(List.this, Ammissione.class));             
                    startActivity(ammissione);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    Intent organizzazione = (new Intent(List.this, Organizzazione.class));             
                    startActivity(organizzazione);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Intent notizie = (new Intent(List.this, Notizie.class));             
                    startActivity(notizie);
                     break;
                case 3:
                    Intent percorsi = (new Intent(List.this, Percorsi.class));             
                    startActivity(percorsi);

                case 4:
                    Intent didattica = (new Intent(List.this, Didattica.class));             
                    startActivity(didattica);
                    break;

                }


        }
    });
  }
```