# How to select multiple images from the grid view and show them to another activity?

Tags: android

**MainActivity look like this I am loading the grid view inside the dialog box.Grid view with images showing properly I am able to pass single image to another activity but not able to pass selected multiple images from the grid view to another activity.**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    showDialog(CATEGORY_ID);
}
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch(id) {

        case CATEGORY_ID:

            AlertDialog.Builder builder;
            final Context mContext = this;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridviewdialog,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
            gridview = (GridView)layout.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
            gridview.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            gridview.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener());
            System.out.println("selecting Ids " + gridview.getCheckedItemIds());
            gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                        final int position, long id) {

                    System.out.println("inside gridview click");

                    switch (position) {

                        case 0:
                            System.out.println("Case 0");
                            Confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SelectedPosterImage.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("imageID", mThumbIds[position]);
                                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            System.out.println("Case 1");
                            Confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(mContext, SelectedPosterImage.class);
                                    intent1.putExtra("imageID", mThumbIds[position]);
                                    mContext.startActivity(intent1);
                                }
                            });

                            break;
                        case 2:
                            System.out.println("Case 2");
                            Confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(mContext, SelectedPosterImage.class);
                                    intent2.putExtra("imageID", mThumbIds[position]);
                                    mContext.startActivity(intent2);
                                }
                            });

                            break;
                        case 3:
                            System.out.println("Case 3");
                            Confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(mContext, SelectedPosterImage.class);
                                    intent3.putExtra("imageID", mThumbIds[position]);
                                    mContext.startActivity(intent3);
                                }
                            });

                            break;
                    }


                }
            });

            Confirm=(Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.Okbutton);
            System.out.println("Confirm id" + Confirm);
            ImageView close = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.close);
            close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setView(layout);
            dialog = builder.create();
            break;
        default:
            dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
}


public class CheckableLayout extends FrameLayout implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;

    public CheckableLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        mChecked = checked;
        setBackgroundDrawable(checked ? getResources().getDrawable(
                R.color.lime_A200) : null);
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

}
public class MultiChoiceModeListener implements
        GridView.MultiChoiceModeListener {
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.setTitle("Select Items");
        mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }

    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    }

    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, final int position,
                                          long id, boolean checked) {
       final int selectCount = gridview.getCheckedItemCount();
        System.out.println("selectedCount "+selectCount);
         final int[] selectIds = (int[]) gridview.getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println("selectIds " + selectIds);



        switch (selectCount) {
            case 1:
                mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");

                break;
            default:
                mode.setSubtitle("" + selectCount + " items selected");
                break;
        }

    }

}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        mContext = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the
    public View getView(final int imagPosition, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CheckableLayout l;
        ImageView i;
        if (convertView == null) {

            i = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            i.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(300, 400));
            l = new CheckableLayout(MainActivity.this);
            l.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 400));
            l.addView(i);


       /*     i.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SelectedPosterImage.class);
                    intent.putExtra("imageID", mThumbIds[imagPosition]);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });*/



        } else {
            l = (CheckableLayout) convertView;
            i = (ImageView) l.getChildAt(0);
        }


        i.setImageResource(mThumbIds[imagPosition]);

        return l;




    }

    // references to our images


}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [move one image from one activity to another activity in android on selcting gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832771/move-one-image-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-android-on-selcting-grid)

Comment: I am not capturing the images from the camera nor I am selecting the images from the gallery I am able to pass single image to another activity but not able to pass selected multiple images from the grid view.